# Understanding React Error Output

Tags: reactjs

First, can I stress that this is a question about the *process* of debugging and not a specific error. As a React/Redux newbie from time-to-time I get a React project that will not 'compile' with a typical error being something like this:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'redux' from 'C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\react-redux\lib\utils'
    at C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
    at process (C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)
    at load (C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
    at onex (C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
    at C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
  stream:
   Labeled {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: [Object],
        pipesCount: 1,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        data: [Function: ondata],
        _mutate: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     _options: { objectMode: true },
     _wrapOptions: { objectMode: true },
     _streams: [ [Object] ],
     length: 1,
     label: 'deps' } }
```

This does not seem to give any pointers as to where the error is, merely what it is. What would be the correct method to determine where the error lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you want to emphasize the *process* of debugging, but the other answers do not touch on that too much.

**I bolded the TL;DR portions**.

---

What you have to know is that **you're running on Node.js first and foremost**. When you say "React/Redux project", you're actually talking about a Node.js project that happens to use the React and Redux libraries.

As such, **if errors pop up when you "compile" your project** (you're likely running `npm start` and running it through webpack, since you're on React), **your first instinct should be, *"there's something wrong with Node..."***

So when an error says "...cannot find module...", it's likely looking for a Node module (which you install using `npm install`, hence the other answers that people showed you).

If any other error comes up, think of it as a Node error first and foremost, unless it explicitly says React or Redux or whatnot. If you Google the error and say that it's from Node, you'll likely get more relevant results.

---

Additionally, your error actually tells you where the error is! This part:

`from 'C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\react-redux\lib\utils'
    at C:\Users\abcde\Documents\ReactTest\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)`

is called a stack trace. It shows you where your program was when the error happened. **Note that it displays a chain of file names** (starting with C:\...), **as well as a row number and column number** (fs.js:**123:15**). That actually already specifies where your error happened, down to the exact cursor position!

The reason why the stack trace is a *chain* of files instead of a single file is to give context: not only do you know which file and which cursor position your error happened in, **you also know how the class/function/module/etc was called** (maybe you missed a crucial argument in some other file).

---

Finally, recognizing these errors just takes experience. You might be having a hard time understanding what the error message is trying to say, but once you run into hundreds of them, you'll soon figure out that "cannot find module" usually means you have to `npm install` something.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed the howto that I was interested in. Interesting that both you and squiroid point to fs.js as being the file with the error. However this is not (as far as I am aware) one of my files. It does appear though that I am going to have to learn more about Node.js as well as React/Redux.

Comment: As others pointed out it was indeed missing redux which is odd because the package.json came from a working project (with redux) and I had alreaded executed npm install.

Comment: If you check your stack trace, you'll see the error comes from inside your `node_modules` folder. `fs.js` may not be one of your files, but it might be part of a module you `npm install`'d.

As for the missing redux, it was likely a peer dependency, which is not automatically installed but is required by one of your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The error simply signifies that you are trying to load redux in fs.js file but it not found. Fs.js file requires the redux but it is not present in your modules.

Can you try

```
npm install redux --save-dev
```

And then try. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command:

```
npm install redux
```

Optionally, you can add "--save" parameter save dependency into package.json, like this:

```
npm install redux --save
```

Usually, when you download a project, the first step you need is to run "npm install", this command will install all dependencies specified in the package.json.